# I need to read data from a file, but unable to read the whole values from it

Tags: c, file-io, text-parsing

```
1 (0.000000,0.000000)   1  429
2 (0.000000,0.000000)   4  58 346 373 465
3 (0.000000,0.000000)   5  94 293 381 431 481
4 (0.000000,0.000000)   3  27 363 458
5 (0.000000,0.000000)   1  471
6 (0.000000,0.000000)   1  79
7 (0.000000,0.000000)   3  111 254 297
8 (0.000000,0.000000)   3  257 425 432
9 (0.000000,0.000000)   2  195 357
10 (0.000000,0.000000)   2  24 95
```

This is the type of data i am trying to read from file named xyz.txt
so i have written some code but still unable to read the file correctly because of the data in discrete format in each line.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main() 

{
    FILE *fp;


    struct net 
    { 

      int id,pc;
      float h,w; 
      int a[10];

    }n;



    fp = fopen("xyz.txt","r+");

        if(fp == NULL)
       {
              printf("Error in opening file");
              exit();
       }
       while(fscanf(fp,"%d   (%f ,%f)  %d\n",&n.id,&n.h,&n.w,&n.pc)!=EOF)
     printf("%d (%f ,%f) %d\n",n.id,n.h,n.w,n.pc);


    fclose(fp);
    getch();
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: For variable-format lines, use `fgets` with a big enough buffer, then parse things out of the string using some combinations of `sscanf`, `strtok`, etc. which make logical sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not consuming the whole line with your `fscanf`, the remaining values trip up your scan. Either use `fgets` to read the whole line and then scan if with `sscanf`, or add `%*[^\n]` to the end of your `fscanf` (which reads characters until it encounters a newline character, and due to the asterisk, ignores those characters).

Also, you should test `fscanf`'s return value against the number of expected fields, which in your case is 4.

```
while (fscanf(fp,"%d   (%f ,%f)  %d%*[^\n]", &n.id, &n.h, &n.w, &n.pc) == 4)
    printf("%d (%f ,%f) %d\n", n.id, n.h, n.w, n.pc);
```

Comment: + 1 Nice, but will have trouble beginning with "123 (123.0, 123.0) 0", `" %*[^\n]""` will consume the next line.  Better to use the `fgets()/sscanf()` approach with `"%d(%f,%f)%d"`

Comment: Have you tested that? Won't the newline stop it? Wait, I see the solution: remove the space before `%*[^\n]`. I agree that `fgets` is the way to go, though.

Comment: Yes, it was that pesky `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(fscanf(fp, "%d (%f,%f) %d",&n.id,&n.h,&n.w,&n.pc)!=EOF){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n.pc;++i){
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &n.a[i]);
    }
    printf("%d (%f, %f) %d\n",n.id,n.h,n.w,n.pc);
}
```

Comment: ur code will ends up in infinite looping i think it is not the way to scan the data for(i=0;i<n.pc;++i) fscanf(fp, "%d", &n.a[i]); and it is not giving the full o/p

Comment: I generally like this better than mine, but it's better to compare `!= 4` (number of fields expected) instead of `!= EOF`, since it will not return `EOF` if, for instance, it only reads one field, in which case it will return `1`.